# How to Filter data in DataSet C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

The word table has 2 fields: WORDID and LEMMA. This code shows all records in the word table. But I want to show only certain records like `SELECT * WORD WHERE WORDID=10`. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleApplication4.DataSet1TableAdapters.wordTableAdapter kata = new DataSet1TableAdapters.wordTableAdapter();

            foreach (ConsoleApplication4.DataSet1.wordRow row in kata.GetData())
            {
              System.Console.WriteLine(row.lemma);
            }

         System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not use all capital letters as it is much harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this..

```
foreach (ConsoleApplication4.DataSet1.wordRow row in kata.GetData())
{
     if(row.wordid==10)
         System.Console.WriteLine(row.lemma);
}
```

Comment: @MasAjum This will work but it won't act like "SELECT * FROM WORD WHERE WORDID=10". It simply loops through all of the items in the table and prints to the console anytime it comes across a row with WORDID = 10. LINQ will give you an actual filtered set of rows.

Comment: OK, Thanks. it's running well

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ?:

```
ConsoleApplication4.DataSet1TableAdapters.wordTableAdapter kata = new DataSet1TableAdapters.wordTableAdapter();

var query = from p in kata.GetData()
            where p.WORDID == 10
            select p;

foreach(var item in query)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.WORDID, item.LEMMA);
}

System.Console.ReadKey();
```

**EDIT:**

It's possible that you might have to perform an additional step which I have coded below.

```
var myTable = kata.GetData();

var query = from p in myTable.AsEnumerable()
            where p.WORDID == 10
            select p;
```

Comment: ConsoleApplication4.DataSet1.wordRow' does not contain a definition for 'WORDID' and no extension method 'WORDID' accepting a first argument of type 'ConsoleApplication4.DataSet1.wordRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @MasAjum Find the line `where p.WORDID == 10`. Delete everything after `where p`. Add the period back and see if intellisense shows your columns. Capitalization matters so if your field is "wordID" and not "WORDID" then that's probably why it's failing.

Comment: i'm waiting for result but so long, not appear. Exactly I need this a good answer because next i want to related with another table

Comment: I get it, already running well. Thanks